# Encapsulate string to ignore quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Working in SSIS, I want to capture error message and insert in into my table.

Here's my insert statement (as SSIS variable):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.info_etl (event_start,event_end,object,event,status,affected_rows,comment)
VALUES
(CONVERT(DATETIME,'"+ (DT_WSTR, 20) @[System::StartTime] +"',103),GETDATE(),'AMDB_ETL_sn_Mirror', 'LOAD','FAILURE', 0 ,
'Component: " +  @[System::SourceDescription] +
"Error:  " + @[System::ErrorDescription] + "')
```

Unfortunately this insert fails once content of variable @[System::ErrorDescription] contains quotes (") as this breaks the string I am inserting to column **comment**.

Example; **@[System::ErrorDescription]**  =

```
Executing the query "RAISERROR ( 'Whoops, an error occurred.',11,1)" failed with the following error: "Whoops, an error occurred.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Is there any smart way of encapsulating portion of string to be treated literally even if contains quotes?

Comment: Don't inject the values, use a parametrised query; then the problem doesn't exist. The Execute Transact-SQL Task has a Parameters Pane; use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in

```
DATETIME,'"+ (DT_WSTR, 20) @[System::StartTime] +"',103
```

I think it should be something like this:

Remove:
'"+ 
and 
+"'

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.